# Writing csv in rows and columns

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, writer

I am so close to being done but cant get my head around this problem.
I am writing to csv and my code keeps giving me this output.

```
 dict,a,b,c,d
 ,,,,
 list,1,2,3,4
```

I want it to be as follows:

```
 dict, list
 a,1
 b,2
 c,3
 d,4
```

The code is:

```
    ##Opening my dictionary .cvs file
    with open('some_file.csv', mode='r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile,)
        DICT = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader if len(rows) == 2}

    ##Opening my enquiry list .cvs file
    datafile = open(self.filename, 'r')
    datareader = csv.reader(datafile)
    n1 = []
    for row in datareader:
        n1.append(row)

        n = list(itertools.chain(*n1))

    headings = ['dict', 'list']

    ##Writing to .cvs file       
    with open(asksaveasfilename(), 'w') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp)
        # write row of header names
        a.writerow(n)

        # build up a list of the values in DICT corresponding to the keys in n
        values = []
        for name in n:
            if name in DICT:
                values.append(DICT[name])
            else:
                values.append("Not Available")

        # now write them out
        a.writerow(values)
```

I tried using `writerows` but this prints the data wrong also

```
d,i,c,t
a
b
c
d
l,i,s,t
1
2
3
4
```

---

**SOLUTION:**

```
    for nameValueTuple in zip(n,values):
    a.writerow(nameValueTuple)
```

Did the trick

Comment: Please show us what `n1` and `n` look like after the first for loop in the code snippet.

Comment: Brice, I added more code see above, hope this helps.

Comment: I'm more wondering about the contents rather than how you get the data. Why don't you print out `n` before writing to the cvs file?

Comment: Hi If I print n during exicution I get the following: ['dict', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']. Does this help clarify?

Comment: Cheers, have a look at my answer. I _think_ that's what you're after. Let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Writing the data directly

```
import csv

DICT = {a:a*a for a in [1,2,3,4,5]}
n = [2, 5, 99, 3]

headings = ['dict', 'list']

##Writing to .cvs file       
with open("try.csv", 'w') as fp:
  a = csv.writer(fp)
  a.writerow(headings)
  for name in n:
    if name in DICT:
       a.writerow([name, DICT[name]])
    else:
       a.writerow([name, "Not Available"])
```

This will result in `try.csv` containing:

```
dict,list
2,4
5,25
99,Not Available
3,9
```

#### Doing the processing first, then writing the processed rows:

You can also do the processing and write everything at once:

```
import csv

DICT = {a:a*a for a in [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
ns = [2,3,99,5]

headings = ['dict', 'list']

ns_squared = [DICT[name] if name in DICT else "NOT_FOUND" for name in names]

print(ns_squared) #=> [4, 9, 'NOT_FOUND', 25]

rows = zip(ns,ns_squared)

with open("try.csv", 'w') as fp:
  a = csv.writer(fp)
  a.writerow(headings)
  a.writerows(rows)
```

This will then result in:

```
dict,list
2,4
3,9
99,NOT_FOUND
5,25
```

#### Using zip to turn columns into row

If you have columns as lists, you can turn these into rows by using the `zip()` builtin function. For example:

```
>>> column1 = ["value", 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> column2 = ["square", 2, 4, 9, 16]
>>> zip(column1,column2)
[('value', 'square'), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 9), (4, 16)]
```

Comment: Pretty awesome and works as you say. One thing though I am having trouble with is the fact that dict is a dictionary and I am taking the list looping it to check if the key is present in the dict and then returning the list item and the value of the key in the dict in two columns. Does this make sense?

Comment: It makes sense, but I'm not sure why you're having trouble. Instead of creating a datastructure, the solution above writes the rows directly to the output. Give me a sec and I'll add another one which creates the values first and then writes them out to show you...

Comment: @gJg Done. Is that what you were after?

Comment: let me check and i will advise. You asked why i am having trouble... well my ex-wife called me an idiot.. maybe thats why :)

Comment: Thank you Brice!! Got it. I added my solution to code above. Used ZIP

Answer (score 0):

Its been long time since I done python, (I'm assuming variable 'values' is an array)

I think your writerow should be something like;

```
#not sure about the syntax, mate...
a.writerow([for x in values])
```

otherwise use bultiin function [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thnx for that... I will look into using 'zip'... Thanks

Comment: Thank you! Got it. I added my solution to code above. Used ZIP

Comment: handy function isn't it...glad it helped